# HTML table cell column mixing fixed widths + percentages

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to do something very basic, a table with 4 columns: 2 columns should be 50px each, the other 2 columns should take 50% of the remaining space each.

I'm surprised to find out that `calc()` does not work for setting width on table cells. So doing something like `td { width: calc(50% - 100px); }` is not a possibility.

Is there a way to achieve this with the `table` element or is using another layout method like flexbox the only choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Width calculation for tables is a bit clunky, but can be improved by using `table-layout: fixed` because then cell widths will no longer be calculated based on what's inside the cells. And then you may not even need `calc()` anymore, although you definitely can.

It should also be noted that a `table` by default takes up *the least width possible*, it usually gets better if we tell the `table` to use 100% width (or whatever is needed in your case).

`width: 100%` combined with `table-layout: fixed` and no `calc()` gives the following results:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

td {
  background: #eee;
  height: 70px;
}

td.fixed {
  width: 50px;
}

td.rest {
  width: 50%;
  background: #fca;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="fixed">1</td>
      <td class="fixed">234</td>
      <td class="rest">a</td>
      <td class="rest">bcd efg</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a grid layout with `grid-template-columns`

---

`grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 1fr 1fr;`

Defines 4 columns in your grid which represent (respectively) 50px,  50px and `1fr` takes one fraction of the remaining space (twice)

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50px 50px 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1px;
}

.col {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

.col:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.col:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: teal;
}

.col:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: navy;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
  <div class="col"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up using this, but I will accept Peter's answer since it's an exact solution to the question.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a grid system (Bootstrap) that can design table, It's a sample

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      2 of 3 (wider)
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col-5">
      2 of 3 (wider)
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: OP requires two fixed with columns